# angucomplete-alt:clearInput error Unable to get property 'originalObject'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm new to angularjs and am trying to use the angucomplete-alt to allow the user to search for worker names.  The search works great, but when I try to clear the input box after the user selects a result the box clears but I get this error message...

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'originalObject' of undefined or null reference
   at $scope.nameSelected (..Worker.php:498:3)
   at callOrAssign (..angucomplete-alt.js:167:11)
   at Anonymous function (..angucomplete-alt.js:124:11)
   at Scope.prototype.$broadcast (..angular.js:18487:15)
   at $scope.deleteRow (..Worker.php:471:6)
   at fn (Function code:2:153)
   at callback (..angular.js:26994:17)
   at Scope.prototype.$eval (..angular.js:18161:9)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (..angular.js:18261:13)
   at Anonymous function (..angular.js:26999:17)
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I hate getting a huge error every time.

this is the box

```
<angucomplete-alt id="workerName"
                placeholder="Name"
                pause="100"
                minlength="2"
                selected-object="nameSelected"
                remote-url="Suggest_Name.php?term="
                remote-url-data-field=""
                title-field="value"
                input-class="form-control">
                </angucomplete-alt>
```

and this is the clear command

```
//clear the autocomplete text box
$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput','workerName');
```

thanks to a user's question I think I've figured it out.  It looks like the nameSelected function fires when the autocomplete is cleared.  Here's nameSelected..

```
//autocomplete callback function
    $scope.nameSelected = function ($item){
        if($item != undefined){ //I just added this
            //console.log($item.originalObject);
            $scope.worker_new.Emp_Name = $item.originalObject.lastname + ', ' + $item.originalObject.firstname;
            $scope.worker_new.PDCWorker_EID = $item.originalObject.UWIdNbr;
            $scope.worker_new.PCA_Option = $item.originalObject.pca_option;
        }
    }
```

adding the check to see if '$item' is undefined has solved my error problem.

Comment: What is in `nameSelected`? Did you initialize it?

Comment: it's a function $scope.nameSelected = function ($item){
  //console.log($item.originalObject);
  $scope.worker_new.Emp_Name = $item.originalObject.lastname + ', ' + $item.originalObject.firstname;
  $scope.worker_new.PDCWorker_EID = $item.originalObject.UWIdNbr;
  $scope.worker_new.PCA_Option = $item.originalObject.pca_option;
 }  sorry about no returns - can't figure out how to add them in here :(